# Kafka offset reset without restarting consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running a kafka consumer with a consumer group test which has consumer 500 messages from Partition 0.Now, I dont want to change the consumer group, but I want my consumer to consume from the 1st message again. I did reset the offset in the server. But, the client again resets the offsets to 500+ and not consuming from 1. But, it works if i stop the consumer and reset the offset in the server and then stop the consumer.

Is there anyway to rest offset without restarting consumer?